# ComboBox display member/value member

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combox box which corresponds to a data grid , when I select a value with the selected index changed function the data grid reflect this.

The problem : The combobox currently displays info like this

```
          Sep  2 2013  1:54PM
          Sep  2 2013  1:55PM
          Sep  3 2013  1:54PM
```

What I want : I want the combobox to keep the same functionalty e.g when I select a value it interactes with the datagrid , But i want it only to display a DISTINCT date e.g the combobox should display :

```
             Sep 2 2013
             Sep 3 2013 etc
```

Anyone got any ideas how to do this ? I'm new to c# and wpf so not sure how

Comment: use string format in the object and then format
http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Answer (score 1):

You could use linq to limit your data and bind it to the datagrid.

I don't know what your data looks like but if its a list or array of strings you could do something like this.

```
//this gets the first 11 characters of the date, you may have to change it slightly for days that have 2 digits but this is just an example, it then makes a distinct list.
dropdown.DataSource = data.Select(s=>s.SubString(0,11)).Distinct();

datagrid.DataSource = data.Where(w=> w.StartsWith(dropdown.SelectedValue));
```

There maybe better ways of doing it but this may help. You may have to add using statements if you havent got them already. System.Collections.Generic and System.Linq

Remember to rebind after.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to filter out your binding source before binding to the data grid.

Comment: cool will try that , any tips on how to do this or where to look ?

Comment: what are you binding to data grid? You can get distinct on both list and datatable. What is your source of databinding?

Comment: I'm setting the combox datasource to be the same as the datagrid , I can get distinct but the problem is if the cell has two different times e.g 9.21 and 9.22 its picking them up as distinct

Comment: add a hidden row to your table (when adding data to datatable) that contains only date value. Then get distinct on that date.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=testing;Userid=abc;pwd=abc");

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ID,date from tbl_test",con);

            con.Open();

            sqldatareader drw = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            dt.Load(drw);       

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            dr["id"] = "0";

            dr["date"] = "Select date";

            dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);

            cmb_test.DataSource = dt;

            cmb_test.DisplayMember = "date";

            cmb_test.ValueMember = "id";

            cmb_test.SelectedIndex = 0; 

           selected changed event change code:

           sqlcommand cmd = new sqlcommand("select ID,date from tbl_test where  id="+cmb_test_send.SelectedValue+",con);

            con.Open();

            sqldatareader drw = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            dt.Load(drw);

            sample_datagridview.DataSource=dt;   `
```